# Share Data type for Json Aeson

Tags: haskell

I´m consuming an API of apple where depending if I look for an album or for a movie the JSON format is different. Some attributes are shared between search but all of them are not the same.

So what I did was just to create a data type for the `Movie` search and another for the `Album`

```
data Album = Album {
     artistName:: [Char],
     trackName:: [Char],
     collectionName:: [Char],
     primaryGenreName:: [Char],
     trackPrice:: Double,
     trackViewUrl:: [Char],
     releaseDate:: [Char],
     previewUrl:: [Char],
     artworkUrl100:: [Char]
} deriving (Show, Generic)

data Movie = Movies {
     artistName:: [Char],
     trackName:: [Char],
     previewUrl:: [Char],
     trackViewUrl:: [Char],
     trackRentalPrice:: Double,
     trackPrice:: Double,
     primaryGenreName:: [Char],
     artworkUrl:: [Char]
} deriving (Show, Generic)
```

Using `Aeson` I serialize/deserialize the data types, but then I realize that Haskell does not allow define arguments with the same name with multiple data types.

But here to deserialize with `Aeson` the name of the attributes must match with the JSON. So I dont know what to do

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A practical way to address such an issue is to put each JSON type in a separate library.

So, the definition of the *album* JSON format would go into one module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module AlbumJson where

import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Data.Aeson (FromJSON, ToJSON)

data JAlbum = JAlbum {
     artistName:: [Char],
     trackName:: [Char],
     collectionName:: [Char],
     primaryGenreName:: [Char],
     trackPrice:: Double,
     trackViewUrl:: [Char],
     releaseDate:: [Char],
     previewUrl:: [Char],
     artworkUrl100:: [Char]
} deriving (Show, Generic)
```

The definition of the *movie* JSON format would go into another module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module MovieJson where

import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Data.Aeson (FromJSON, ToJSON)

data JMovie = JMovie {
     artistName:: [Char],
     trackName:: [Char],
     previewUrl:: [Char],
     trackViewUrl:: [Char],
     trackRentalPrice:: Double,
     trackPrice:: Double,
     primaryGenreName:: [Char],
     artworkUrl:: [Char]
} deriving (Show, Generic)
```

These types are essentially static type representations of a wire format of which you have no control (the service owner controls the API), so it's good practice to have what in [DDD](http://amzn.to/WBCwx7) is known as an *anti-corruption layer*.

Notice that I also prefixed the type names with `J`, which leaves the names `Album` and `Movie` free for use in a proper domain model.

You can then use qualified imports to write some code that uses both types at once, if you need to.

[Here's a GitHub repository](https://github.com/ploeh/PureInteractionsInHaskell) with an example of that design approach, where you can see how I've used it, and how I've composed it. The two corresponding examples are the `OpeningJson` and `ReservationJson` modules. An example of code that uses both those modules is `ReservationsHttpClient`.

Comment: Nice, simple and elegant solution. Thanks